# Getting Unauthorized Error 401 in Volley after passing JWT in header from Shared Preference

Tags: android-fragments, django-rest-framework, sharedpreferences, android-volley, jwt

I am using `Volley` to fetch `DjangoRestApi`.I get `JWT` after passing username and password.JWT is stored in `SharedPreference` and later passed in subsequent request.I have three `Fragments`.After Login and saving JWT in Preferencce I go to Second Fragment where I am passing Token in Headers to fetch data but I get Error 401.After I go to Third Fragment and again come back to Second Fragment then I get Correct response.How to resolve this ?

Comment: 401 means that the token header is not passed. Can you check if the header is received by printing request.META in your view?

Comment: Yes. I have checked but token is stored in shared preference but not retrieved in Second Fragment.But retrieved in Third Fragment.